# Why doesn't transposing matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I was helping a friend with linear algebra,

particularly I was teaching how to check if a collection of vectors $v_1, ..., v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent (assuming the vectors are given vertically). Now the techniques I gave him was to apply reduced row echelon form to the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\ v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_k^T  \end{bmatrix} $$

And if one doesn't discover any "zero" rows then the vectors are indeed linearly independent.

So as an example, verifying that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Are linearly independent occurs by applying the reduced row echelon form to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

yielding

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

So we conclude that there are no dependent vectors.

Now my friend suggests that running the same routine, but without transposing the vectors can also let us conclude about dependence.

His claim:

The number of non zero rows in:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & ... & v_k\end{bmatrix} $$

Corresponds to the number of dependent vectors. I disagreed with a counter example, to which he responded with an argument involving "counting pivots" that I couldn't make sense of.

Has anyone here seen something like that? Would they be able to enlighten me on how to test independence/dependence without taking transposes?

Comment: row rank = column rank

Comment: Your friend is correct.  The number of independent rows always equals the number of independent columns.  That's not actually trivial to prove, it's proven on page 72 of Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: What was your counter-example?.

Comment: However, when they're not independent, extracting a maximal list of independent vectors  from the initial list of vectors is harder than when you transpose. Also, note that transposing then row-reducing amounts to make elemenntary operations on *columns*, i.e. column reducing.

Comment: @harvey the same vectors i've given when RREF'd as is, give a zero row, but the trick is to note that already as many rows as vectors aren't zero, so the extraneous zero row is meaningless

Comment: consider the case $V$ is a square real matrix, and define the transpose as $\langle Vx, y \rangle =\langle x,V^T y \rangle$ for any two (real) vectors $x,y$. You get that $rank(V)$ is obviously $= rank(V^T)$ because of the symmetry of the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$ @GregoryGrant

Comment: @user1952009 Yeah but it's true for all matrices square or not over all fields, real or not.

Comment: @GregoryGrant non square matrices become square matrices with zero padding, and the argument works for complex matrices obviously (but I admit I don't know how to treat it in the finite fields case)

Comment: @user1952009 to do it in general you base it on the fact that the rank plus the nullity equals the dimension of the domain (of a linear transformation).  The proof of that is pretty straightforward if you write things in terms of a basis for the null space expanded to a basis for the whole space and then apply the transformation.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I'm thinking the inner product still exist whatever the field is, so yes the argument stays the same

Comment: Well your proof is still relying developing some concepts relating to the inner product, so the proof is still not trivial.  The most basic argument could probably be based on thinking about how row-reduced echelon form of a matrix relates to its transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column- and row rank of a matrix coincide, so it does not matter whether you transpose the matrix or not.

Answer (score 0):

- **Elementary row operations alter the linear dependences among the rows, but they do not alter the row space.** Clearly the new rows introduced by any row operations are in the row space of the old rows.  And vice-versa, since row operations can be inverted by other row operations.  Since they do not alter the row space, **they do not alter the dimension of the row space.**
- **Elementary row operations alter the columns space, but they do not alter the linear dependences among the columns.** Consider $$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} m_{1,1} & \cdots & m_{1,c} \\ \vdots\ \ \ \ & & \vdots\ \ \ \ \\ m_{r,1} & \cdots & m_{r,c} \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\  \vdots \\ x_c \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0  \end{array} \right] $$ and suppose the $x$s are not all $0$.  Then the vector of $x$s is a linear dependence among the columns. If that vector is a solution to the system before the application of a row operation, then it still is afterwards.  Since the linear dependences therefore do not change, the dimension of the column space does not change.

Once the matrix is fully reduced, it is easy to see that the dimensions of the row and column spaces are equal.  Since they are equal after the row operations, and the row operations don't change them, they are equal before the row operations. **Conclusion:** In every matrix, the row and column spaces have equal dimensions.